# get GPS longitude and latitude from separate class - Android

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I'm looking for a way to get from the GPS it's longitude and latitude variables from separated class which is not on the main activity. I must get these values whenever the users changes location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is Separate class to Access  longitude and latitude.

```
public class AppLocationManager implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    private Criteria criteria;
    private String provider;

    public AppLocationManager(Context context) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1,
                0, this);
        setMostRecentLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));

    }

    private void setMostRecentLocation(Location lastKnownLocation) {

    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.location.LocationListener#onLocationChanged(android.location.
     * Location)
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lon = (double) (location.getLongitude());/// * 1E6);
        double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());// * 1E6);

//      int lontitue = (int) lon;
//      int latitute = (int) lat;
        latitude = lat + "";
        longitude = lon + "";

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.location.LocationListener#onProviderDisabled(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.location.LocationListener#onProviderEnabled(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.location.LocationListener#onStatusChanged(java.lang.String,
     * int, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

You Call longitude and latitude from your mian Activity Class.

```
AppLocationManager appLocationManager = new AppLocationManager(YourActivity_name.this);
appLocationManager.getLatitude()
  appLocationManager.getLongitude();
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, now i want the latitude and longitude to always show in a toast on my screen. How can i do it from the main activity?

Answer (score 1):

To show the parameters in a Toast use the following code.

```
lat = appLocationManager.getLatitude();
lng = appLocationManager.getLongitude();
Toast.makeText(ct, lat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(ct, lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But the question is GPS, not NETWORK Provider. Not sure why this is marked as "Best Answer"